# Can you say 日本のたべもの instead of わしょく?

Tags: word-choice, food

In  the sentence 'わしょく は おいしい です' (Japanese food is delicious), can you instead say '日本 の たべもの は おいしい です' and it will translate the same?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It depends on what you mean.

Normally, 和食{わしょく} means Japanese traditional dishes, such as [nikujaga](https://www.kurashiru.com/recipes/352c9948-d5b7-4248-b48d-ea531cbeec56), [sukiyaki](https://www.kurashiru.com/recipes/5a5a70f2-1100-48f7-94e3-bf3ac7668baf) etc. A typical washoku set menu may look like [this](https://www.kurashiru.com/recipe_cards/d3f59afd-3837-4beb-8ed2-5969468607ca) for example.

日本の[食べ物]{たべもの} would technically mean everything you can eat in Japan, and at least include dishes that are originally from other countries. For examples, [ramen](https://www.kurashiru.com/recipes/a62e961f-8e3e-4277-ac70-dc1f6ae1deb4) and [curry](https://www.kurashiru.com/recipes/4afa40f9-5ca9-4a86-9125-f6dbe8326cb5) are originally Chinese/Indian, but they are fairly localized and typical ones are definitely called 日本の食べ物 but not 和食. (Ramen is called 中華{ちゅうか}=Chinese, but Japanese ramen are not usually found in China. Similarly for Japanese curry in India, as far as I know.)

Comment: What about 日本料理?

Comment: @mudri In terms of meaning, they are practically the same, as suggestd by [Wkipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E6%96%99%E7%90%86). In terms of usage, 日本料理 is used more often when you are talking about food culture or the Japanese food as provided in a very authentic manner. For example, 朝食はいつも和食です is ok (meaning you eat rice and miso soup for breakfast), but you cannot say 朝食は日本料理です.

Answer (score 4):

destroyer2009
I am Japanese.
I read your question.
As a Japanese, I think the two expressions are a little bit different each other as @sundowner answered.
Washoku represents Japanese traditional (original？) cuisine, for example, Sushi, Tenpura, Udon and so on.
But the second expression means foods in Japan are delicious.
So, even Pasta and Sandwich are included.